# RocketRaid 640 on kernel 5.3

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel

I am a new Linux user and am currently trying to get my RocketRAID card installed on the latest version of Ubuntu. Every piece of data I can find on how to install the drivers for it are outdated and fail at the DKMS stage. Is there anyone out there using this card currently, or can even help me figure out if I can make this work?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 5.3. I did manage to get the card working on kernel 4.15.18 an am currently using UKUU to work my way through the list of kernels until I find one that fails. I will update with what I figure out, but for now assume that this is the last good kernel.

This is the link I found the ______________ that worked for 4.15.18.  https://bitbucket.org/yurac/rr64x/src/master/

The card I am specifically using throws both 1103:0640 and the pxl controller 1065:8609 at me when I used... I forget the command already.  The version of the card I have is the Rocketraid 640 Gen1 and not the 640L.

I am a 5-day-old at Ubuntu and Linux in general so if you think you can or want to help then be gentle.  My computer knowledge isn't that bad, but I'm a Windows guy this hook caught me. I am learning more and more about the terminal and am not scared to have to wipe this unit again if things go sideways.  I've reloaded Ubuntu a dozen times since I started this for various reason.

Comment: After everything I did I broke the install.  Wouldn't open anything in the GUI, did a reinstall, tried downgrading the kernel to 4.15.18 first and threw the whole system into a boot crash that wouldn't even allow for the Grub menu to work.

Back to square one I guess.

Comment: AFAIK, RocketRaid drivers do not support anything beyond 4.15 at the moment. Be aware, Highpoint typically does not offer bleeding edge support. They will likely support kernel 5.4, but not for some months. I had the same problem with 4.15.